# Get Internal IP Address From DHCP Hostname

Tags: networking, ssh, home-networking, ip, dhcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How access network computers by name](https://superuser.com/questions/81547/how-access-network-computers-by-name)

I would like to try and get an internal ip address of one of the computers on my network. The reason for this is I have a little home server box downstairs but every time I want to SSH into it I have to open my router configuration and go on the DHCP client table and look at the IP address. For example I would like to be able to go `ssh ell-sever` instead of `ssh 192.168.1.105` or whatever it happens to be.

My network configuration is like so:

- Router downstairs that is connected to the Internet and is running a DHCP server
- My server computer (ell-server) is a headless pc connected to the router via ethernet cable. Running Ubuntu 11.04 Server Edition
- My laptop upstairs (ell-laptop) that is running Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop Edition connected wirelessly
- Other (irrelevant) computers - 2 x Windows XP, 1 x Xubuntu - all connected with cables.

(It seemed to me the method of connection isn't useful information but I put it in anyway - just in case. If I have missed any information please tell me)

Do I have to run a DNS server on one of my computers? If so which one? And does that mean I will have to run a DDNS client on each computer?

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 1):

Since the network is not very large, and probably won't change very often, perhaps consider using static IP settings (instead of DHCP) and client-based [HOSTS files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) instead of DNS.

Comment: To better specify static options, you can set a static IP outside your DHCP range on the server, or if your router permits (and most can do this) set DHCP to reserve a specific IP for the server's MAC address.